# Why cant android store entire app data to sd card?

Tags: android

Why is only some part of the app's data stored on the SD card and the rest remains in the internal memory ?
I am looking for a more technical explanation, taking into account the types of storages involved and their handling by the OS.

Comment: Technically it could, by using a unix-style file system maintained in an image in the card's generally less capable filesystem.  But this is both unreliable (card might vanish) and tricky to secure against tampering/spying by other apps or (controversial as a goal) the user.  Securing it against tampering and reading when stored on insecure media would require encryptiong and signing, and that's difficult to do well on a writable volume that can be snapshotted at multiple points in time.  It's somewhat moot today as the "external storage" is usually now implemented atop the internal storage.